# Name for plane curve $r=\sqrt{a^2\sin^2\theta+b^2\cos^2\theta}$

Tags: polar-coordinates, solid-of-revolution

I would like to know how is the following figure called (or the solid of revolution made by this figure around the horizontal axis).

$r=\sqrt{a^2\sin^2\theta+b^2\cos^2\theta}$

[image]

[Plot of the figure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bwk49.png)

Comment: Welcome to MSE!  Please see the [help center](https://math.stackexchange.com/help) for the guidelines on what we expect in a question.  What else can you tell us here?  What the axis of revolution that you are revolving this about?

Comment: It's also known as an inversion (or inverse) of an ellipse.  See also an older post [*here*](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1873042/name-this-2-dim-parametric-curve).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you pass back to Cartesian coordinates using $x=r\cos\theta,r=\sin\theta$, this becomes $$r^2=a(y/r)^2+b(x/r)^2\implies r^4=(x^2+y^2)^2=ay^2+bx^2$$
which is the form of the [hippopede](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hippopede). As noted in the linked Wikipedia article, it has a few special cases and properties; in particular, it's the pedal curve of an ellipse.